# How do the equations of motion of the Foucault pendulum result in the specific law of parallel transport?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differential-geometry, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

I have read that the precession in the plane of oscillation of a Foucault pendulum is equivalent to parallel transport of tangent vectors on a sphere. I am interested in proving this statement using the equations of motion.

Consider a Foucault pendulum with the small angle approximation. Let $\phi$ be the longitude angle and $\theta$ be the angle from the north pole. Let $x$ denote the displacement of the pendulum along the latitude and $y$ denote the displacement along the longitude. As a first step, I want to show that the standard Foucault pendulum equations
$$ \ddot{x} + \omega^2 x = 2 \Omega \cos\theta \dot{y}$$
$$ \ddot{y} + \omega^2 y = -2 \Omega \cos\theta \dot{x}$$
are equivalent to the equation of parallel transport along the latitude
$$\dot{x} + \Omega \cos\theta \Gamma^\phi_{\phi \phi}x + \Omega \cos\theta \Gamma^\phi_{\phi \theta}y=0$$
$$\dot{y} + \Omega \cos\theta \Gamma^\theta_{\phi \phi}x + \Omega \cos\theta \Gamma^\theta_{\phi \theta}y=0$$

I am guessing that one has to remove the dynamical phase component before showing the equivalence, but I am unsure how to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A possible strategy might be as follows:

Instead of treating the Foucault pendulum equations as equations for a pendulum bob swinging in a plane, solve for a conical pendulum.

The equations then allow two solutions: one for a clockwise moving pendulum bob, and one for a counter-clockwise moving pendulum bob. These two solutions have a slightly different frequency. Of course, the planar motion of the actual Foucault pendulum can be thought of as a superposition of the clockwise and counterclockwise conical pendulum solutions.

The common factor of the two cases is the latitude dependence.

In the case of the Foucault pendulum:
The two equations, for the x-direction and the y-direction have the same form as the two equation for a system of [two coupled oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation#Coupled_oscillations).

Close to the poles the direction of a plumb line is close to parallel to the orientation of the Earth's axis. That gives a coupling such that the oscillation transfers between x-direction and y-direction at the same angular frequency as the overall rotation of the system.

The further away from the poles the larger the angle between plumb line and Earth axis. Accordingly the coupling is weaker. As a consequence the transfer between x-direction and y-direction occurs *slower* than with full coupling.

That is how the latitude dependence comes into the Foucault pendulum dynamics.

General discussion

It is important to be aware that the the veering of the plane of swing and geometric phase of parallel transport (along a sphere) only coincide in approximation.

That is, the correpondence obtains only when small effects are left out of the equation. Conversely, as you push for a more exhaustive calculation of the pendulum plane of swing you get deviation from  correspondence with parallel transport.

To show why that is the case I start with an extreme example, and from there I will come back to Earth.

Thought demonstration:
We take a very small celestial body, an asteroid for example, and we construct a Foucault pendulum with an extremely heavy bob. Let the mass of the pendulum bob be 1/10th of the mass of the asteroid.

With the gravity from the asteroid so feeble the pendulum will have a very long period, but that doesn't matter; for the Foucault effect to occur the *frequency* of the oscillation is immaterial.

First case: a non-rotating asteroid.
Because of the 1:10 mass ratio the swing of the pendulum bob will affect the asteroid significantly. Under those circumstances: the process of the pendulum bob swinging is a process of *exchange of momentum*. For every swing of the pendulum bob the asteroid will change orientation correspondingly.

Second case: a rotating asteroid, and the pendulum is at a latitude between the equator and the poles.
As in non-rotating case: the pendulum bob is exchanging momentum with the asteroid. The veering of the plane of swing is a process of *momentum exchange* betweeen the pendulum bob and the asteroid.

In the case of a Foucault pendulum on Earth: the effect of the Foucault pendulum on the Earth is totally unmeasurable of course, but regardless of that: the veering of the plane of swing of the Foucault pendulum is a process of *exchanging momentum with the Earth*. (If there would not be any exchange of momentum then the veering of the plane of swing would be in violation of conservation of momentum.)

So:
You may succeed in showing that for the equations that you are using there is a corrrespondence with parallel transport, but that result will be valid only for that level of approximation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the physics of the problem, as you have explained very well in your problem. However, I am looking for the connection to differential geometry, which I know will be only valid under several assumptions. As stated in the question, I want to get from an (approximate) equation for the Foucault pendulum to an equation for parallel transport.

Comment: @MohitKumar My opinion: if such a sequence of steps can be constructed at all then it will be one that hinges on the correlation with latitude. There is the geometric phase that is incurred in parallel transport along a latitude line, and there is the veering of the plane of swing being slower the closer to the Equator. I believe those two have only one thing in common: that dependence on latitude. I believe that common element is not enough to carry a derivation. If you do try: I expect you will end up with a [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) derivation.